# Google Sheets to Salesforce with OAuth2 - Question about post mapping

Tags: post, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I am trying to get [this code](https://github.com/appsscripted/sfconnect) to work.  I know it is a bit outdated, I have fixed it where it needed to be.  I am trying to upload data to an Object in Salesforce.  Here is the script I am trying to get working:

```
function upload(object, payload) {
  var sfService = getSfService();
  var userProps = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var props = userProps.getProperties();
  var name = getSfService().serviceName_;
  var obj = JSON.parse(props['oauth2.' + name]);
  var instanceUrl = obj.instance_url;
  var queryUrl = instanceUrl + "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/" + object +"/";
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + sfService.getAccessToken()
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: payload,
    method: "POST"
  });
}
```

What I don't understand is the payload format.  For example, I have my Account object and I want to load a row of data into it.  I also have headers for each column of data that map it to the correct fields in Salesforce.  How can I insert data into Salesforce using this method while simultaneously mapping it to the headers?  Would I create a JSON with it and pass that as the payload?

Comment: Where is the script getSfservice();

Comment: Can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: Sorry, I only provided the part I was having issues with.  getSfservice is in another gs.  It is a pretty large code.  You can find the github in the link at the top of my post.  Here is the URL to the Salesforce Lightning REST API Developers Guide, I hope that's what you meant:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by using the following script to convert my payload into a JSON object (as well as changing my DateTime fields to Date fields, which was causing some issue):

```
function tableJSON(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
      obj[arr[0][j]] = arr[i][j];
    }
  }
  return JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

This formatted my payload, which was just my data range in my designated sheet.  Hope this can help someone else!